# Key value pair in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, entity-attribute-value, hstore

I need to save key value pairs in PostgreSQL database which will have some basic info regarding the record.

After some googling on the topic I found out `hstore` is one of the options. But even after going through the documentation I am not able to figure out how to add records in a table with a `hstore` column and also how they are returned in the result and how I can parse it.

I am totally new to PostgreSQL so any code reference will be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the [**`hstore`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html) data type, you need to install the additional module hstore first. Once per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
```

[`CREATE EXTENSION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html) has been added with Postgres 9.1. Older versions have other methods.

Read more about the pros and (many) cons of *EAV* (Entity-Attribute-Value) storage in an RDBMS under this [related question on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/20759/3684).

In Postgres 9.2+ consider [**`json`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) as alternative.
In Postgres 9.4+ consider [**`jsonb`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html).

Comment: Nowadays there's also a JSONB datatype