# Select column name and value from table

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql, hstore

If I have the following table in a PostgreSQL database:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    

A       a       1       
B       b       2
```

Is there a way to get the column name for each value *without explicitly specifying the column names*? I.e. have a result set like:

```
Col1    A
Col1    B
Col2    a
Col2    b
Col3    1
Col3    2
```

Comment: The only way to do this is using a stored function with dynamic SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You may be forgetting about JSON and hstore ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: a right, I always forget hstore's feature to turn anything into an hstore

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course, you could write a PL/pgSQL function and query the catalog table [`pg_attribute`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-attribute.html) yourself. But it's so much easier with one of the following:

#### JSON

The function [**`row_to_json()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-TABLE) provides functionality that goes half the way. Introduced with Postgres **9.2**:

```
SELECT row_to_json(t, TRUE) FROM tbl t;
```

You don't have to mention the column names at all, the function derives them from the table type.

[->SQLfiddle demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/48975/2)

But you'll need [**`json_each_text()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-TABLE) from Postgres **9.3** to go all the way:

```
SELECT json_each_text(row_to_json(t)) FROM tbl t;
```

To get a sort order like you display:

```
SELECT (json_each_text(row_to_json(t))).*
FROM   tbl t
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

(It's unclear how you want to sort exactly.)
Untested. SQLfiddle does not provide Postgres 9.3, yet.

### hstore

However, you can do the same with the [additional module **hstore**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE). Available since **8.4**. Install it once with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
```

Details:
[Key value pair in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032540/key-value-pair-in-postgresql/15034597#15034597)

Query:

```
SELECT (each(hstore(t))).*
FROM   tbl t
ORDER  BY 1,2;
```

That's all.
Again, no SQLfiddle, since one can't install additional modules there.

Comment: The JSON solution did exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Aw man, this is so great, and exactly what I need, but I'm stuck with PSQL 8.4 here. :(  Any pointers?

Answer (score -1):

You can get column names from reader in c#

```
string CONNECTION_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM FINANCE_PAYMENTS";
            SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(CONNECTION_QUERY,onnection);
            SqlDataReader reader = comand.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    //this line will give you Column name and value
                    JO.Add(reader.GetName(i),reader[i].ToString());
                }
            }
```