# Get access to OLD.myLoopVariable / NEW.myLoopVariable in a plpgsql trigger function?

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I try to get access to a loop variable that is a column name of a table, to get old and new data of each column.

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $emp_stamp$
DECLARE
  current_column_name text;
BEGIN
  FOR current_column_name IN
    SELECT column_name 
    FROM information_schema.Columns 
    WHERE table_schema = TG_TABLE_SCHEMA AND table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME 
    LOOP
      IF (OLD."current_column_name" <> NEW."current_column_name")
      then ...
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$emp_stamp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_function();
```

And I have a next error: `ERROR: record "old" has no field "current_column_name"`
I tried without quotes (`""`), but got the same result.

How can I get access to old and new column data?
I need to save all changed data, like a history with fields: `column_name`, `old_value` and `new_value`.

Comment: If you want to check if _any_ column has changed, just use `if (old is distinct from new)` no need to loop through all columns. But you will however not know which column(s) _were_ different

Comment: no, I exactly want to save all changed data, like a history with fields: column_name, old_value, new_value

Comment: See here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus or here http://okbob.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html or here http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/ for some sample implementations of that

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parameterize identifiers in plain SQL. You would need **dynamic SQL** for that, i.e.: build a query string dynamically, *then* execute it, which can be cumbersome and error-prone. There is a simpler alternative for your case, especially since you need to cast all columns to a common data type anyway, the natural choice being `text`.

It's also not possible to *loop* through fields of a record or row type. That's why you are currently reading metadata from the information schema to walk through columns, but you can have that simpler, too.

Use the extension **[`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html)** and its tools. Install it once per database:

- [Key value pair in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032540/key-value-pair-in-postgresql/15034597#15034597)

Convert a row to `hstore` with the obvious function [`hstore()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE):

```
hstore(OLD)
```

It returns a type `hstore`, which is a key/value store with all values converted to `text. Now you have various options. Probably simplest: unnest with`each()` and join:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_function()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _col text;
   _old_val text;
   _new_val text;
BEGIN
   FOR       _col, _old_val, _new_val
      SELECT key , o.value , n.value
      FROM   each(hstore(OLD)) o  -- (key, value)
      JOIN   each(hstore(NEW)) n USING (key)
      WHERE  o.value IS DISTINCT FROM n.value  -- only changed columns
   LOOP
     -- do something
   END LOOP;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If all you want is to insert changed columns into an audit table, make it a **single SQL command** and no looping at all:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_function()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO audit_table
         (tbl_schema     , tbl          , col , oldval , newval)
   SELECT TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME, key , o.value, n.value
   FROM   each(hstore(OLD)) o  -- (key, value)
   JOIN   each(hstore(NEW)) n USING (key)
   WHERE  o.value IS DISTINCT FROM n.value;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

***Or*** you can convert `hstore` to a 2-dimensional key/value array with [`%# hstore(OLD)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE) and loop through it like instructed here:

- [Postgres - array for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783422/postgres-array-for-loop/9784986#9784986)

---

For more sophisticated needs there are audit solutions, [like a_horse commented.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42659642/how-in-postgresqlplpgsql-trigger-to-get-access-to-old-myloopvariable-new-myl#comment72454666_42659642)